# Proper way to create POST routes in Slim Framework Version 3.0

Tags: php, api, post, routes, slim

I'm setting up a Restful API using Slim Framework Version 3.  I've used yet V2 and it works great.  However,  this new API is required to be set up in V3.  And there are some changes from V2 to V3.
I have no problem using the GET methods.  However, POST method id giving me problem and I'm sure is in the way one must request the form contents.

This is how it worked in V2:

```
$app = Slim::getInstance();
$request=$app->request->getBody();
$form_data = json_decode($request);
$stmt->bindParam("id_itme", $form_data->id_itme);
```

This way I was able to capture form elements an then pass them to the query.

In version 3,  have workaround but still get errors.  If I hardcode the values to be inserted inside the query,  the insert is done into my DB, mysql 5.6 by the way.  But when letting the parameters, is impossible to insert,  indeed *mysql* gives me error of *not null values* are allowed,  so the query is processed but the form is not passing the values to be inserted.

This is a basic *insert* end point,  in which I removed the debugging *try and catch*, just to make it work.

```
$app->post('/add', function ($request, $response, $args) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO dim.dim_city   (id_dim_country, city, city_status) VALUES ( :id_country, :city, '1');";
$db = getDB();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$body = $request->getBody();
$form_data =$body;
$city=$form_data['city'];
$id_country=$form_data['id_country'];
$stmt->bindParam(':id_country', $id_country, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':city', $city);
$stmt->execute();
$id_city= $db->lastInsertId();
$db = null;
echo json_encode($id_city);
});
```

It gives me a 500 error message or as I stated before,  a *mysql* error in which the problem is that the id_country variable is not recognized so, not nulls are allowed to be inserted in the table.

Any ideas on how to properly declare post routes. I've just checked some documentation in slim website, Rob Allen's v3 skeleton and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call to `$request->getBody()` body returns `Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface`. You probably want to use `$request->getParsedBody()` instead.

```
$app->post("/foo", function ($request, $response) {
    $data = $request->getParsedBody();
    print_r($data);
});
```